# passing parameter to Angular application state

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular, angular-fullstack

I have made yoman angular fullstack app setup.

I am making use of ui.router in application.

I have defined state parameters as

```
.state('tour', {
    url: '/tour',
    templateUrl: 'app/tour/tour.html',
    controller: 'tourCtrl',
    params : {tourName: null, },
  })
```

I am able to pass parameter to this state within application.

when my application goes to external link.

I want to get back to one of the state of my angular application with some parameter. so how can i do that??

Please Help me to do that .. Thanks

Comment: append those parameters into your URL, form that URL, and navigate to that URL. you can re-write your URL as /tour/:tourName ... And add a resolve...

Comment: suppose i'm running it on my local system. i have url as localhost:9000 then i supposed to do as localhost:9000/tour/America    it is correct or wrong

Comment: it doesn't matter whether you run it locally, or on the server. If you have a state linked to a particular URL, the Url would always take you to that state. And the Url is perfectly correct. And you can access the value= "America" in $stateParams.

Comment: http://localhost:9000/tour/tourName:AustraliaNewZealand  this is the url i'm trying to hit is it correct or not... while i have designed stateparams as tourName

Comment: change the url to tour/:tourName, and StateParams= { tourName : "AustriaNewZealand"}. Then its perfectly correct. And yes, add resolve: tourName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass parameters and maintain states using stateParams, and then maintaining them in the URL. For your understanding, I have added a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview

Observe the console whenever you navigate to Route1 tab, and then observe the code:

```
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1/:place",
        params: {
          place: null
        },
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                template: "route1.viewA"
            },
            "viewB": {
                template: "route1.viewB"
            }
        },
        resolve :{
          place: function($stateParams){
            console.log($stateParams);
            console.log("url", window.location);
            return $stateParams.place;
          }
        }
    })
```

Try this on localhost. It would work the same way on localhost, or any place where its hosted.

Comment: should i have to do like this http://localhost:9000/tour/:StateParams=%20%7B%20tourName%20:%20%22AustriaNewZealand%22%7D.

Comment: @bhaveshgujar: yes. Did you understand the plunk I attached?

Comment: Could you attach a working copy of your code, so , we can figure out what's happening?

Comment: i made go through it but not able to work  out it with my system ... i my system i'm passing stateparams using ui-sref but how can send same through external system.

Comment: i have used                                                                       $state.go('booking',{room:data,tourData:{
          date:$scope.showDate,
          code:$scope.items.code,
    }}) how can i do same thing from external application

Comment: you don't need to pass those stateParams through external application. From there, you can navigate to your web-app, to a particular URL, something like, localhost:8000/tour/:booking/:room/:tourData.

Comment: ok i'm able to pass single param but how can i pass muliple in same way

Comment: @bhaveshgujar: you can pass as many parameters as you want. just append them to the URL, and when you are passing, pass an object, like {city: Delhi, country:India, state: Delhi}. and change your url to localhost:9000/booking/:city/:state/:country